# How to evaluate this integral with a bessel function

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

I have to evaluate the following two integrals that I would like to solve,

```
 Sin[θ] 2 π BesselJ[0, k Sin[θ] (μ[j] - μ[i])] Exp[2 k^2 σ^2 Cos[θ]^2],
```

and

```
Sin[\[Theta]]^2 2 I \[Pi] BesselJ[1, k Sin[\[Theta]] (\[Mu][j] - \[Mu][i])] Exp[2 k^2 \[Sigma]^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2]
```

w.r.t. $\theta$ between the interval [0, $\pi$]. The first equation consists of a zeroth-order Bessel function and the second a first-order Bessel function. These equations arise by evaluating the inner product of a wavefunction which resembles a collection of 2D Gaussian state along the y-axis with centres at $\mu[i]$.

I have tried to evaluate the integral using the `Mathematica` sybolic language but with no results. Can a suitable transformation be suggested to achieve an analytic solution to both equations or a solution by any other means?

Thanks very much for your help!

Note, I posted this [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/105513/how-to-evaluate-this-integral-with-a-bessel-function) in Mathematica Stack exchange and was advised to ask on the Mathematics Stack exchange.

Comment: For the first one, the substitution $x=\sin\theta$ should work. Are you expecting that it should be equal to $0$, by any chance?

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo, I am hoping that it is not zero, but I will try this substitution.

Comment: @PierpaoloVivo; The suggested substitution will generate a 0 for both the upper and lower limits giving 0.

Comment: No, you cannot use it this way...you'd need to split the interval $[0,\pi]$ into $[0,\pi/2]$ and $[0,\pi/2]$...but anyway on second thoughts I fear it won't work...they seem very complicated to handle analytically